# Taskbar right click application context menu for windows vista and higher

Tags: c#, taskbar, windows-messages

I need to know the code for taskbar right click application context menu for windows vista and higher in C#. For older versions of windows this code is 0x313. In vista and higher this code means shift + right click. I can't find the code for right click only in application context menu in taskbar.

Comment: duplicate of [Handling Right Click/Left Click of Task-bar Button in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597281/handling-right-click-left-click-of-task-bar-button-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I know that this question is quite a long time ago, but If anyone are searching for it like me now (at 2018), it's called Jump List, you can checkout sample of JumpList in **Windows API Code Pack** (https://stackoverflow.com/a/25048686/2133965) at **Samples/Shell/TaskbarDemo/CS**

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is 
[Associating a Context Menu with a Windows Forms NotifyIcon Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984293%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> The Windows Forms NotifyIcon component displays an icon in the status
>   notification area of the taskbar. Commonly, applications allow you to
>   right-click this icon to send commands to the application it
>   represents. By associating a ContextMenu component with the NotifyIcon
>   component, you can add this functionality to your applications.

```
public NotifyIcon notifyIcon1 = new NotifyIcon();
public ContextMenu contextMenu1 = new ContextMenu();

public void createIconMenuStructure()
{
   // Add menu items to context menu.
   contextMenu1.MenuItems.Add("&Open Application");
   contextMenu1.MenuItems.Add("S&uspend Application");
   contextMenu1.MenuItems.Add("E&xit");

   // Set properties of NotifyIcon component.
   notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
   notifyIcon1.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon
      (System.Environment.GetFolderPath
      (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)
      + @"\Icon.ico");
   notifyIcon1.Text = "Right-click me!";
   notifyIcon1.ContextMenu = contextMenu1;
}
```

Comment: I already have menu when right clicking on **tray** icon. Now I need to duplicate it for a button in **taskbar**. Different things.